# Keycloak User Federation Provider Module Logging Level

Tags: logging, module, wildfly, slf4j, keycloak

I have developed my custom user federation provider using Keycloak 1.5.0 guidelines and i have installed it as jboss module under

```
com.my.module.userfederation
```

In my project i have defined my Logger using slf4j facade with log4j implementation.

For testing reason i need to set log level to DEBUG so i entered the wildfly console then in the configuration/logging page i have added a new category_

```
category:  com.my.module.userfederation
Log LEVEL : DEBUG
```

in standalone.xml

```
 <logger category="com.my.module.userfederation">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
  </logger>
```

But when i run my application no changes are made on log console...as log level is always INFO.

I guess it depends on the module installation format... so how can i set correctly my log level?

Comment: Do you have a log4j configuration file in your deployment?

Comment: No just slf4j as pom dependency provided

Comment: I'm going to show my ignorance here, but what version of WildFly are you running on? FWIW you shouldn't need to include slf4j or an slf4j binder.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't installed my providers as jboss modules as I'm running the server standalone and loading them from the filesystem. You can edit the standalone.xml under `${keycloak.root.dir}/standalone/configuration`:

```
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="FINEST"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
```

And since you're using `slf4j`, if you haven't already, you might have to add the `org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14`library to your project to make `slf4j` use `jul` under the hood. This is what worked for me.

Comment: OMG, `TRACE` level takes only 5 minutes to display all the startup log lines.